# PyCharm cannot resolve reference in __init__.py with Django project apps

Tags: django, pycharm

I am at my wits end with this issue, and would love some help resolving this.

I have a Django project with a bunch of sub apps as such:

```
my_project/
    manage.py
    my_project/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    app_root/
        __init__.py
        app1/
            __init__.py
            models.py
            views.py
            urls.py
            templates/
                [various templates].html
        app2/
            __init__.py
            models.py
            [etc]
        app3/
            [etc]
```

in my django settings.py i have installed apps as such:

```
app_root.app1,
app_root.app2,
```

In PyCharm, I've tried various things but essentially have Content Root as the top "my_project/" and app_root, app1, app2, etc as Source Roots.  I've tried just having `app_root` as the only Source Root, and I've tried having only `app1`, `app2`, etc only as Source Roots, but nothing makes any difference.

Everything functions fine. app runs and everything.  However, PyCharm has an inability to resolve my apps.

However, if i try this:

```
import app_root
...
def some_function(self):
    app_root.app1.models.My_Model.objects.all()
```

it will highlight app1 with the error `"Cannot find reference 'app1' in '__init__.py'"`
This also means it can't do autocomplete anywhere in the path while doing `app_root.app1.` - it has no idea about models, views, etc. despite having an (empty) `__init__.py` in every directory.

I also cannot use any refactoring because it always says "Function is not under the source root"

I've spent countless hours trying to get PyCharm to behave but simply cannot find a way to do it. Is there any way this can be done so PyCharm will autocomplete my apps and not keep giving inspection warnings?

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar issues. My solution; within the PyCharm preferences I added a path to `app_root` in my active Python Interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I've got `app_root` and all the apps identified as "source roots", and also have "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" selected.  I don't readily see any other way to add `app_root` to my Python Interpreter (it only seems to allow package installation under Python Interpreter settings)

Comment: Just did an update to latest PyCharm version, apparently there are some changes to the Interperter. They removed to possibility to add an path to your interperter.
At the moment I only defined the `app_root` as source folder, don't really know yet if this the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After an exchange with the PyCharm folks, here is what I learned:

Django imports all apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` variable and their models using `__import__` for its own purposes.
In your case, it runs

```
__import__("app_root.app1")
__import__("app_root.app1.models")
```

After that, you call `import app_root` and obtain module `app_root` with `app_root.app1` and `app_root.app1.models` already imported by internal Django code

Fact that Django imports apps and models is Django internals, it is undocumented and may be changed in future releases. We believe you should not rely on it in your production code, nor PyCharm should.

Here is example in bare python (no django):

```
__import__("encodings.ascii")
import encodings
print (encodings.ascii.Codec) # this code works, but PyCharm marks "ascii" as "unknown module"
```

So basically, it's not supposed to work as `import app_root`, but Django funkiness is masking that.